# Following OOP paradigms

Tags: java, oop

I’m learning Java and have recently started my first project. The idea of this project is to pass one input argument - path to file/folder, which would be analyzed in order to find all files with predefined extension, parse them and create objects based on the results of parsing to  store for future.

So far I’ve written all the code and my project structure (simplified) looks like that:

- Class defining resulting object
- Class that analyzes the input parameter (exists, is file, is folder) and processes it, returning list of all suitable files
- Class that parses suitable files and creates objects

The question is - am I following OOP with that structure?

From what I’ve read on the web the last two classes seem to look like polterheists. But I don’t think that it is a good idea to move the logic of the third class to the object class because it consists of lots of methods (define current section of the file, strategy to parse each separate section).

I am learning on my own and don’t want to start my journey by cultivating bad habits.

Comment: As said by Stanislav it's hard to give real concrete feedbaks without checking your code. I would however advise you to think about classes as _being_ things rather than _doing_ stuff (i.e. classes as objects instead of procedures). For instance, you may have: a class which instances_are_ resulting objects, a class which instances _are_ folders able to find suitable files, a class which instances _are_ suitable files, etc. There are a lot of OOP flavors (understand: lots of possible approaches and no silverbullet) but thinking this way should help you to build cohesive classes.

Comment: @EmmanuelChebbi, classes "being" works for simple cases, but at some point it stops working - you run out of _things_. And start coming up with non-existing things _around the behaviour_ (properties) that they share. Good examples from Abstract Algebra (from which programmers need to learn): Groups, Rings, Fields, Vectors, Modules.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure to understand your point. I'd describe a "thing" as a "cohesive set of properties" which may or may not exist in the real world. As such I have no problem with e.g. a `Ring` or `Vector` class, or even a class representing a behavior/algorithm such as `DijkstraAlgorithm`.

Comment: @EmmanuelChebbi, this means that statement "classes as being _things_ rather than _doing_ stuff" is meaningless. Because every time we have something that _does_ stuff we'll be able to come up with a name and it will become a _thing_.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev my point was to encourage a vision based on objects rather than on procedures. Of course you can always take a class that does something and name it but, based on my experience (which is a bit limited, I admit), beginners that focus on the "do" tend to end up with data bags and "services" objects that manipulate them. I'm not saying that's bad design, not at all, I'm saying that IMHO that's not OOP which is more about objects having their own responsibilites and collaborating together to make a bigger system.

Comment: @EmmanuelChebbi, I think the reason beginners end up with Anemic Model (data bags) is because at the beginning of 2000's Java developers were told that it's a good thing (because of EJB1 & EJB2?). And it's the _experienced_ developers who do this and teach others this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am learning on my own and don’t want to start my journey by cultivating bad habits.

You're saying this like you have a choice :)

From what you described it seems reasonable, of course w/o seeing the code we can't say. And even if you show the code - 100 people will have 100 opinions, there's a lot of debates around OOP.

What's important is not to look at your design as something static. Once your app starts to be more complicated you'll have to re-work some of it.

PS: stackoverflow doesn't like this kind of questions since everyone will have an opinion. You'll have to find other resources if you keep having such questions.

Comment: To complete the last statement: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) may be better places to ask design questions.

Comment: The above question can be split into two distinct entities. ① The above question as posted would be off-topic on Code Review as it doesn't include any _code_ for us to review. ② The question 'am I following OOP?' is on-topic on Code Review. Again, only if Maksim provides their code in the body of the question. Future visitors, our [guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) should help explain whether posting on Code Review is right for your question.